# Not able to sort array using Date.parse()

Tags: javascript

I want to sort my array according to the timestamp.My array is this

```
[
  {
    who: 'User',
    msg: 'how are you?',
    time: '9:24:19'
  },
  {
    who: 'Bot',
    msg: 'I am fine. Thank you. How are you?',
    time: '9:24:30'
  },
  {
    who: 'User',
    msg: 'hi',
    time: '9:24:36'
  },
  {
    who: 'Bot',
    msg: 'hello i am Joe',
    time: '9:24:47'
  }
]
```

And when I'm sorting it as a string it is working fine but when I use Date.parse(time) nothing his happening.The problem of sorting it as a string is that when I have 23:11:8 and 23:11: 36, it considers 23:11:36 as the small one.
What to do?

Here is my code

```
var msg1 = msg.sort((a, b) => {
  console.log('sorting');


  var nameA = a.time; // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.time; // ignore upper and lowercase
  console.log(nameA + " " + nameB + " " + Date.parse(nameA) + " " + Date.parse(nameB));
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    console.log('sorting');
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    console.log('sorting');
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
})
```

Comment: `Date.parse("23:11:36")` is `NaN`.

Comment: Then how do i parse the string as date

Comment: Just append any fixed date to it like `var time = '9:24:19'; var date = new Date('2018-01-01 ' + time);console.log(date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you don't need `Date.parse`. You need some transformation to make your times comparable. Something like this. This is simplified solution. You may need to consider AM|PM.

```js
let msgs = [{
    who: 'User',
    msg: 'how are you?',
    time: '9:06:19'
  },
  {
    who: 'Bot',
    msg: 'I am fine. Thank you. How are you?',
    time: '9:24:50'
  },
  {
    who: 'User',
    msg: 'hi',
    time: '9:24:36'
  },
  {
    who: 'Bot',
    msg: 'hello i am Joe',
    time: '9:24:47'
  }
];

let sorted = msgs.sort((a, b) => {
  let tA = a.time.split(':');
  let tB = b.time.split(':');
  return (tA[0] * 60 * 60 + tA[1] * 60 + tA[2]) > (tB[0] * 60 * 60 + tB[1] * 60 + tB[2]) ? 1 : -1;
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: This worked for me when i used parseInt with all the values for the case i had the problem with i.e when the time is returned in this format 23:01:3.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to sort the array with the default time **10:01:44** you need a proper time format in order to parse the date like **Mon Mar 19 2018 10:01:44** so that it will be able to **parse** it

Here is a sample function that sort the array using  **Date.parse()**

```js
function SortUsersOrder(usersArray){
    let sortedOrder = usersArray.sort(function(a, b){
        let firstDate = Date.parse(a.time);
        let secondDate = Date.parse(b.time);
        if(firstDate < secondDate) return -1;
        if(firstDate > secondDate) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    return sortedOrder;}
    
    
var sample = [ { who: 'User', msg: 'how are you?', time: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 10:01:44' },
 { who: 'Bot',
   msg: 'I am fine. Thank you. How are you?',
   time: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 10:01:43' },
 { who: 'User', msg: 'hi', time: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 10:01:41' },
  { who: 'Bot', msg: 'hello i am Joe', time: 'Mon Mar 19 2018 10:01:40' } ]


console.log(SortUsersOrder(sample))
```

Comment: This is also not sorting the array

Comment: It is not possible to sort the array with the default time "10:01:44" you need a proper time format in order to parse the date like "Mon Mar 19 2018 10:01:44" so that it will be able to parse it. as shown in above example

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
msg.sort((a, b) => {
    var nameA = Date.parse('2018-01-01' + a.time);
    var nameB = Date.parse('2018-01-01' + b.time);
    if (nameA < nameB) { return -1; }
    if (nameA > nameB) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
```

Date.parse() need you to insert date, not just time

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1 - Sorting string as date:

Just append any fixed date to it like:

```js
var time = '9:24:19';
var date = new Date('2018-01-01 ' + time);
console.log(date.toLocaleString())
```

### Part 2 - Sorting `msgs` array by time:

<sup>*(Latest message is shown first)*</sup>

```js
var msgs = [{who:'User',msg:'how are you?',time:'9:06:19'},{who:'Bot',msg:'I am fine. Thank you. How are you?',time:'9:24:50'},{who:'User',msg:'hi',time:'9:24:36'},{who:'Bot',msg:'hello i am Joe',time:'9:24:47'}]

var sortedMsgs = msgs.sort((a, b) => {
  var timeA = new Date('2018-01-01 ' + a.time);;
  var timeB = new Date('2018-01-01 ' + b.time);;
  return timeB - timeA;
});

console.log(sortedMsgs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

TESTS:

```js
var msgs = [{who:'User',msg:'how are you?',time:'9:24:5'},{who:'Bot',msg:'I am fine. Thank you. How are you?',time:'9:24:45'},{who:'User',msg:'hi',time:'9:24:46'},{who:'Bot',msg:'hello i am Joe',time:'9:24:20'}]

var sortedMsgs = msgs.sort((a, b) => {
  var timeA = new Date('2018-01-01 ' + a.time);;
  var timeB = new Date('2018-01-01 ' + b.time);;
  return timeB - timeA;
});

console.log(sortedMsgs.map(s => s.time));
```

Comment: But if the time is 9:24:5 which is actually 9:24:05..When using this code rather all the others...i get the result that 9:24:5 is bigger than 9:24:45

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue, I added some time (demo above) and it is sorted like: `"9:24:46",
  "9:24:45",
  "9:24:20",
  "9:24:5"`, so 46 first and 05 or 5 at last.

Comment: As I think you are testing with some different data, as in my tests code there is no time value like `9:24:47`

Comment: The answer you posted has this example [{who:'User',msg:'how are you?',time:'9:06:19'},{who:'Bot',msg:'I am fine. Thank you. How are you?',time:'9:24:50'},{who:'User',msg:'hi',time:'9:24:36'},{who:'Bot',msg:'hello i am Joe',time:'9:24:47'}]

Comment: Yes, that `9:24:50` is showing first as we have the 2nd object time as `9:24:50` not `9:24:5`. Also, the code is sorted in descending order if you want it in ascending order than just reverse the subtraction inside sort.

Comment: That's what i'm saying..it is not working for me when using 9:24:5...for other values it is working fine..this code is considering 9:24:5 as 9:24:50

Comment: I tried your code and as i wanted in ascending order i reversed the subtraction..it was working with all cases other than that i mentioned..that's, why i went for the other answer which did not have dat.parse(), ..but in that too, I had to use parseInt()..to get my desired results